# Why is Carbon and other elements (not available) in StoppingPowerData?

Tags: syntax, warning-messages, curated-data

I am trying to look up StoppingPowerData for a number of elements and while this snippet works for several I have tried (Aluminum, Lead, Iron for example), I get a result of (not available), but no error, when I try with others, such as Carbon. I've tried specifying an isotope of Carbon as well as different incoming particles and different energies.

```
StoppingPowerData[
Entity["Element", "Carbon"],
{"Particle" -> "Proton","Energy" -> Quantity[500,"Kiloelectronvolts"]},
"LinearStoppingPower"]
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the "possible issues" in the help docs: "Not all properties support all particles". `Missing[NotAvailable]` just means there's no data entered for those lookup parameters.

Comment: Is it possible to find out what parameters it does support? StoppingPowerData[] shows Carbon as being an available parameter, but I've tried a range of energies and different properties and everything seems to give not available?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `StoppingPowerData` is just a construct to interface with a compilation of NIST data, along the same lines as `ChemicalData` and `ThermodynamicData`. They cite three primary sources in the help docs:

- [NIST Standard Reference Database 124 (2005).](https://www.nist.gov/pml/stopping-power-range-tables-electrons-protons-and-helium-ions)
- [NIST Standard Reference Database 126 (2004).](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/nist-tables-of-x-ray-mass-attenuation-coefficients-and-mass-energy-absorption-coefficients)
- [NIST Standard Reference Database 8 (2010).](https://www.nist.gov/pml/xcom-photon-cross-sections-database)

Mma provides an error message to let you know when you specify energies that are out of range:

> StoppingPowerData::orng: Energy should be between 10000. eV and
>   1.1*10^10 eV.

**Also, data is not available for all property/particle/element combinations.** `Missing[NotAvailable]` is returned in cases where `StoppingPowerData` can't find anything for the specified lookup parameters. You can use `TableForm` to make a rough visual check:

```
Module[{props, test},
 props = StoppingPowerData["Properties"]; 
 test = StoppingPowerData[
     Entity["Element", "Lead"], {"Particle" -> "Proton", 
      "Energy" -> Quantity[500, "Kiloelectronvolts"]}, #] & /@ props;
 TableForm[Transpose[{props, test}]]]
```

[image]